# SKLabelNode text values won't update when stored in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, sprite-kit

If I change the `text` attribute on a `SKLabelNode` after adding it as a child, the text will update in the view. But if I add it to an `NSMutableArray`, retrieve it, and *then* change the value, the text will not update in the view.

My best guess would be that either `-addObject:` or `-objectAtIndex:` of `NSMutableArray` are copying the objects instead of referencing them, but as you can see from their documentation: ([`-addObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject%3a), [`-objectAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex%3a)), neither one says anything about objects being copied.

*Note: you may need to reload the pages for the `-addObject:` and `-objectAtIndex:` documentation before you're taken to the right spot on the page.*

What's going on? Why aren't my changes propagating?

`MyScene.h`:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *labels;

@end
```

`MyScene.m`:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

@synthesize labels;

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Consolas"];

        label.text = @"Test String";
        label.fontSize = 65;
        label.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                     CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        [labels addObject:label];
        [self addChild:label];

        // If I uncomment the following line, the text won't update.
        // label = [labels objectAtIndex:0];

        label.text = @"Test String: Reloaded";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you creating the array somewhere? It looks like the labels pointer might be nil.

Comment: Uh oh, I think you might be right.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. You should post that as an answer so you can get points.

Comment: I swear, about 80% of my development time is spent making really dumb mistakes and spending forever trying to figure them out.

Comment: I hope I was able to save you some of that time. :)

Comment: If you get into the habit of using the debugger to set a breakpoint and inspect variables to verify they are what you 'expect' they are, you can can avoid wasting time. Debugging would have pinpointed this issue quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you haven't created the NSMutableArray. Sending messages to nil will silently fail and nothing will happen, without any hint as to why.